# How exactly does potential difference remain the same across the branches in a parallel connection of capacitors?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, potential, capacitance

I understand how charges  get distributed across the branches in parallel connection of capacitors and how they remain the same in series connection. But I am not able to get an intuition in the equivalence of potential difference across branches in parallel connection.I understand the explanation using  Kirchhoff's voltage law but is there a more fundamental explanation to it?

Comment: Do you have the same difficulty with resistors in parallel?

Comment: @sammygerbil Yes I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a comment more or less points out, two parallel connected circuit elements have *identical* voltage across; this is essentially a definition of parallel connection.

Think about it, how does one measure the voltage across a circuit element?  *One places a voltmeter in parallel with the circuit element*.

So, to say that two capacitors are parallel connected is to say that they have identical voltage across.  Put another way, if they don't have identical voltage across, they aren't parallel connected.